# Content of Control in a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to set a Custom WPF control in a ResourceDictionary.

ResourceDictinary (InformationContainer.xaml):

```
<ResourceDictionary 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:dxdb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/demobase"
             xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
             xmlns:l="clr-namespace:LISA"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:LISA.ViewModels"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LISA.ContentPages.Notification.SubModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="notificationTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <local:BasicInformation Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <local:PatientInformation Grid.Row="1"  Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0"  />
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="{x:Static l:Resources.Ok}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

My MainWindow.xaml:

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors" 
             xmlns:cp="clr-namespace:LISA.ContentPages"
             xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
             xmlns:l="clr-namespace:LISA"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:LISA.Models"
             x:Class="LISA.ContentPages.Notification.NotificationControl" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" FontSize="{DynamicResource fontNormal}">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:NotificationControlModel x:Name="Model" />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/LISA;component/ContentPages/Notification/SubModels/InformationContainer.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/LISA;component/ContentPages/Notification/SubModels/InformationHeader.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <vm:NotificationControlModel x:Key="viewModel" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <dxg:GridControl Name="notificationGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InformationContainers}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ShowLoadingPanel="True" Loaded="view_Loaded">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:CardView ShowGroupPanel="False" ShowColumnHeaders="False" Name="view" NavigationStyle="Row" CardTemplate="{DynamicResource notificationTemplate}" CardHeaderTemplate="{DynamicResource notificationTemplateHeader}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" AllowEditing="True" CardLayout="Rows"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>

</UserControl>
```

So now, I would like to create an instnace of the "InformationContainer.xaml" and to set the custom UI elements (the data in the model). But If I create a new instance like: InformationContrainer ic = new InformationContrainer(); I am not able to access the custom UI Elements "

Comment: "But If I create an Instance of this object, I am not able to access those controls".. are you referring to the datatemplate itselft? or your <local: /> ?

Comment: To the tamplate itself.

Comment: You don't "access" the UI elements in WPF. What do you want that for? Use DataBinding instead.

Comment: yes. Thats what I actually mean. Please check my question again. I updated it.

Comment: You can't create instance of InformationContrainer, it is not a class. You don't have to do it actually. And why are you using `DynamicResource` and not `StaticResource` for templates?

Comment: Because it is essential for the dataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are actually adding your dictionary to the app.xaml under its resources

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="YourDictionaryName.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </RosourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Yes. I implemented the ResourceDictionary in the app xaml. Maybe I have to make my question more clear. Please check it again